# I am getting error while loading <a href="linktext.com">linktext.com</a> from SQL with help of PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, hyperlink

i am tring to load some data from SQL on a webpage using php, but everything stop when there is a hyperlink in sql text data ... like  linktext.com.

tried html special character but not working.

Comment: Question is unclear to me as not much information is provided by OP.

Comment: what error u have getting?update your code

Comment: What does "not work" mean? You need to show some actual code, what sort of error you are facing - basically do your own debugging! We can't help you if you don't give us the information we need to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a guess that you need escape the quotes or use single quotes in your SQL.

I would have a stab and say your code is outputting an incorrect format for the links.

```
$url="<a href="link.com">link.com</a>"; ## << This is the value from the database
echo $url;
```

As you can see there are too many double quotes, you need to stick to a scheme of double quotes in your code and single in variables (the database in this case) or escape the strings

```
$url = "<a href=\"link.com\">link.com</a>";
```

or

```
$url = "<a href='link.com'>link.com</a>";
```

Comment: $url = "<a href='link.com'>link.com</a>"; THANKS .... WORKING